# CGridView Parse error in when i try convert data

Tags: yii

Error in CGridView Yii, what i need to do, what fix it:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\kaskad\www\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1


'date'=>array(
    'value' => $this->rus_date("j F Y H:i ", $data->date),
),
```

Comment: `value` should be a string containing a php expression that will be `eval`'d. Put single quotes around the value.

Comment: Then my method `rus_date` not founded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the controller in the value expression as follows using `$this->grid->controller`:

```
'date'=>array(
    'value' => '$this->grid->controller->rus_date("j F Y H:i ", $data->date)',
),
```